# ActiveMQ Artemis not starting without SSL enabled configuration

Tags: ssl-certificate, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0. Firstly I configured setup with SSL and artemis was starting without errors then I wanted to test my setup without SSL, I removed all SSL related settings from `broker.xml` and `bootstrap.xml` and now when I trying to run Artemis I'm getting this:

```
2021-10-13 07:34:26,047 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.18.0 [amq1, nodeID=bee15e5b-2bf7-11ec-887f-0800277c53f8]
2021-10-13 07:34:26,263 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2021-10-13 07:34:26,297 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2021-10-13 07:34:26,548 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2021-10-13 07:34:26,571 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2021-10-13 07:34:26,573 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.13.5
2021-10-13 07:34:26,580 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2021-10-13 07:34:26,595 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2021-10-13 07:34:26,600 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/home/vagrant/artemis-broker/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/vagrant/artemis-broker/etc/keystore.jks is not a valid keystore
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.component.WebServerComponent.start(WebServerComponent.java:263)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.addExternalComponent(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:908)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:126)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:155)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:103)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:130)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50)
2021-10-13 07:34:26,847 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter
2021-10-13 07:34:26,848 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services
2021-10-13 07:34:26,875 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin
2021-10-13 07:34:26,878 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin
2021-10-13 07:34:26,902 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.18.0 [bee15e5b-2bf7-11ec-887f-0800277c53f8] stopped, uptime 11.619 seconds
```

Not sure what Jolokia property is overriden. Did I forgot to do something else?

`bootstrap.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">
   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
   <server configuration="file:/home/vagrant/artemis-broker/etc//broker.xml"/>
    <web bind="https://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
</broker>
```

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>amq1</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 31.25 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 32000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>150000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>1628000</page-sync-timeout>
      <global-max-size>204Mb</global-max-size>

      <connectors>
        <connector name="amq1">tcp://amq1:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq2">tcp://amq2:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq3">tcp://amq3:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq4">tcp://amq4:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq5">tcp://amq5:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq6">tcp://amq6:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
       <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
       </acceptors>
       <broadcast-groups>
           <broadcast-group name="artemis-broadcast-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
               <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
           </broadcast-group>
       </broadcast-groups>
       <discovery-groups>
           <discovery-group name="artemis-discovery-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
           </discovery-group>
       </discovery-groups>
      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
            <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>3</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
            <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
             <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="artemis-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
      <!-- Other config -->
      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <master>
            <group-name>artemis-group-1</group-name>
            <quorum-vote-wait>12</quorum-vote-wait>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            <!--for auto failback -->
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          </master>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="DLQ">
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">            
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>    
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis is failing because the bind attribute of the web element is using the HTTPS protocol:

```
<web bind="https://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
```

To fix this issue the bind attribute should use HTTP protocol:

```
<web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
```